# How can I use 'selectedPanel` in storybook?

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I noticed a property in [Storybooks Options Docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/options-parameter/#per-story-options) called `selectedPanel` which I assume will allow me to pre-select an addon panel.

I'm unclear on how to use it. The example is:

```
options: { selectedPanel: 'storybook/a11y/panel' }
```

What I don't understand is where the 'storybook/a11y/panel' string comes from. What if I want to preselect the 'Source' panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue and managed to find out that the `panelId` can at least be found in the addon's `register` source code step. For example, I wanted to open [`Readme`](https://github.com/tuchk4/storybook-readme) tab for certain stories.

I ended up finding the id of the panel in [`registerWithPanelTitle.js`](https://github.com/tuchk4/storybook-readme/blob/master/packages/storybook-readme/src/registerWithPanelTitle.js#L6), and then using it with the `storiesOf` API like this:

```js
.addParameters({
  options: { selectedPanel: 'REACT_STORYBOOK/readme/panel' },
})
```

For a11y, it can be found in [`constants.ts`](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/v5.3.18/addons/a11y/src/constants.ts#L2).

Although, I've searched for those in the distributed `node_modules` versions in my case.

P.S. If you want to reorder the panels for all of the stories globally, the list that the addons are imported in handles it.

Comment: Thanks so much, this has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking to default to the knobs panel: `selectedPanel: 'storybookjs/knobs/panel'` appears to work!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `@storybook/addons-essential` in `main.js` and simply added `@storybook/addon-controls` to the front of the `addons` array option, like so:

```
module.exports = {
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-controls', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
    ...
}
```

This puts the controls tab first, which is auto-selected.